# Ruby on rails check_box always rendering checked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

my rails checkbox is always checked in the dom.  How can I make it so when the page loads it's checked if the object is true or not?

```
= f.check_box :split_funding, {class: "split_funding", :disabled => @survey.completed?, id: "split_funding_#{school.id}", "data-attribute" => "split_funding", "data-id" => school.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it the `checked` attribute like so:

```
= f.check_box :split_funding, {checked: @survey.split_funding, class: "split_funding", :disabled => @survey.completed?, id: "split_funding_#{school.id}", "data-attribute" => "split_funding", "data-id" => school.id}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'if the object is true', so I am assuming that `:split_funding` will return true/false. If it's a relation, you can chain `:present?` on the end to check for presence of the relation.